# Passing multiple datas through bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do the same with multiple data, with `data-todo` attribute, but it doesn't work. Could you help me?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditTodo", function () {
    var todoId = $(this).data('id');
    var todoName = $(this).data('todo');
    $(".modal-body #todoId").val( todoId );
    $(".modal-body $todoName").val( todoName );
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#editTodoDialog" class="open-EditTodo btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-id="$todo_id" data-todo="$todo_name">EDIT</a>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 200px;" id="editTodoDialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" align="center">
    <div class="modal-content" style="width: 350px;">
      <div class="modal-header" align="left">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit to-do:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" align="center" style="height: 65px;">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="todo.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="todoName" id="todoName" value="" class="form-control" style="width: 230px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="todoId" id="todoId" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, `data-id` works just fine, but `data-todo` doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put those two data items together.

Ex:

```
<a id="todolink" href="#editTodoDialog" class="open-EditTodo btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-todo='{"id":12,"todo":"xyz"}'>EDIT</a>
```

Now you can retrieve the array like this:

var todoId = $('#todolink').data('todo').id;

var todo = $('#todolink').data('todo').todo;

Comment: Nadeeth, I was thinking about this solution, but I need two different variables. Every one of them will be used for different purposes (identification).

Comment: Then you can try using a JSON object inside the array. Ex: [{"id":$todo_id, "todo":$todo_name}] . I did not test this, please let me know if it works. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I tested, it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/7j2h3Lu4/ . And I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will work perfectly you have some syntax problem in displaying data.

```
$(".modal-body $todoName").val( todoName );
```

here instead of $todoName it will be,

```
$(".modal-body #todoName").val( todoName );
```

otherwise, there is no other problem means you can use two different data attribute to pass data.

Comment: Do you mean the OP should replace `$todoName` with `#todoName` in the selector?