# How To Pass multiple data id in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am trying to pass multiple data id into bootstrap modal.
When I am passing hardcoded data to data id, it is working fine

```
<a id="testB" href="#my_modal2" data-toggle="modal"   data-book-id='{"id":10,"name:'xyz','gender':2>Open Details</a>
```

and I am accessing values by

```
var Id = $('#testB').data('book-id').id;
var name= $('#testB').data('book-id').name;
var gender= $('#testB').data('book-id').'gender';
```

But my problem is -
I need to pass all values by *for loop*.

```
<a id="testB" href="#my_modal2" data-toggle="modal"   data-book-id='{"id":<%= rows[i].id%>,"name:<%= rows[i].name%>,'gender':<%= rows[i].'gender'%>}>Open Details</a>
```

and I am getting all values ***Undefined***

```
*var Id = $('#testB').data('book-id').id;*
```

I am using this for refrence
[Passing multiple datas through bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118039/passing-multiple-datas-through-bootstrap-modal)

I am using node js and ejs template
what is the proper way to pass multiple data-id by using for loop

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check waht `console.log($('#testB').data('book-id'))` show ?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a closing bracket and your quotes are mixed up between single and double:

```
<a id="testB" href="#my_modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id='{"id":10,"name":"xyz","gender":2}'>Open Details</a>

<a id="testB" href="#my_modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id='{"id":<%= rows[i].id%>,"name":"<%= rows[i].name%>","gender":<%= rows[i].'gender'%>}'>Open Details</a>
```